# how to do action on *next* word?

Tags: org-mode, text-editing

Is there a function (or some kind of prefix command) that will allow me to do an action to the **next** word I type, not the word under point or the region? Currently:

- `upcase-word` puts the word under the point in uppercase
- `org-emphasize` bolds or italicizes the word under point

But when typing text, I often want to do this to the **next** word I type, the one I haven't typed yet (using <kbd>SPC</kbd> as the delimiter).

So I want function I can call **before** I enter a word that will place `*` on either side of the next word I type, without my having to type the closing `*`.

Let's say my keybinding for bold-next-word is M-S-b.

Sample input:
This is an <kbd>M-S-b</kbd>important<kbd>SPC</kbd>point.

Desired output:

```
This is an *important* point.
```

`org-emphasize` is my main use case, but it would be nice to be able to do this with upcase, downcase, etc.

Comment: Something like this?:  `(defun org-emphasize-next-word () (interactive) (insert " ") (org-emphasize ?*))`

Comment: Hmm, with that I get this: `This is an  *important point *`

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted the upcoming word while the cursor was at the end of the current word.  My mistake.

Comment: I do want the upcoming word, the problem is getting the point past the closing `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very cheap way to accomplish the job for "embolden next word."

- Hello `M-s-b` world `M-s-m` → `Hello␣*world*.␣`← point is here
- Hello `M-s-b` world `M-s-w` → `Hello␣*world*␣`← point is here

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-b") '(lambda () (interactive)
                 (just-one-space)
                 (insert "**")
                 (backward-char 1)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-w") '(lambda () (interactive)
                 (move-end-of-line nil)
                 (just-one-space)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-s-m") '(lambda () (interactive)
                 (move-end-of-line nil)
                 (insert ".")
                 (just-one-space)))
```

Here's another solution, adjusting Drew's answer so that it applies to the next word.

```el
(define-minor-mode embolden-next-word
    "Make the next word you type bold."
  nil 
  :lighter " EMBOLDEN"
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (define-key map (kbd "SPC") (lambda ()
                      (interactive)
                      (save-excursion 
                        (goto-char (get-register 'p))
                        (insert "*"))
                      (insert "* ")
                      (embolden-next-word -1)))
        (define-key map (kbd ".") (lambda ()
                    (interactive)
                    (save-excursion 
                      (goto-char (get-register 'p))
                      (insert "*"))
                    (insert "*. ")
                    (embolden-next-word -1)))
            map)
  (if embolden-next-word
      (set-register 'p (point))
    (set-register 'p nil)))

(global-set-key "\C-o" 'embolden-next-word)
```

If you want a really generic solution, maybe the thing to do is define a macro that would allow you to generalise that minor mode so you can *foo* next word.

PS. As Drew indicates, it's easier to apply markup commands to words after you've already typed them.  For instance, here's a binding I use a lot:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "H-o") (lambda () (interactive) (upcase-word -1)))
```

Comment: The embolden-next-word minor-mode above works perfectly. Where would I add `expand-abbrev` to get it to expand emboldened abbrevs the same way Emacs normally expands abbrevs when I hit SPC?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a way to type and have words you type be emboldened automatically.

That's easier to do after you enter the word, as soon as you hit a non-word char. On `post-command-hook` you can check whether `(looking-back "\w\W")` (a word char followed by a non-word char), and if so, `save-excursion`, `backward-word`, insert a `*`, `forward-word`, and insert another `*`.

Something like this:

```el
(defun embolden-last-word ()
  (interactive)
  (when (and (eq last-command 'self-insert-command)
             (looking-back "\\w\\W")
             (not (eq (char-after) ?*)))
    (save-excursion
      (backward-word) (insert ?*) (forward-word) (insert ?*))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'embolden-last-word)
```

(Be aware that this emboldens **words**, since that's what you asked for.  For example, in a mode like `emacs-lisp-mode`, since `-` is not a word-constituent character, you will get `*foo*-*bar*` and not `*foo-bar*`.  If you want the latter, then either make `-` be a word constituent in your mode or use `symbol` instead of `word` in the code.)

You could of course bind a command to a key that toggles add/remove of `embolden-last-word` from `post-command-hook`, so you can quickly enable and disable emboldening.  For example:

```el
(define-minor-mode toggle-embolden-word
    "Toggle making words you type bold."
  nil nil nil
  (if toggle-embolden-word
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'embolden-last-word)
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'embolden-last-word)))

(global-set-key "\C-o" 'toggle-embolden-word)
```

(And if you do that then you do not need to do the `(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'embolden-last-word)` shown above. Just use the toggle key to turn it on/off.)

Comment: Naturally, if you turn on `toggle-embolden-word` before you type the next word, and turn it off afterwards, then it effectively works as "embolden-next-word" :-)

Comment: @JoeCorneli: You do not *have* to, and may not want to, turn it on and off again, for each word. Toggle it on, leave it on until you no longer want bold words, then toggle it off. A key to embolden the next *existing* word, which you can use like `upcase-word`, is useful because you can *repeat it to continue with subsequent words*. Your `embolden-next-word` has no such utility. `toggle-embolden-word` provides this for words you have yet to type. If only a rare word is emboldened then yours might make sense, but in that case it is enough to type `*` twice. (But OP apparently disagrees. ;-))

Comment: I need to embolden words frequently, and always just a single word.